# Fast way to build a hash set, single or multiple thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, hash, hashset

i want to know which why is faster to build a hashset.

my process like this:

1, DB access (single thread) , get a **large** list of IDs.

2,
Plan A

```
foreach( var oneID in IDs)
{
    myHashSet.add(oneID);
}
```

Plan B

```
Parallel.ForEach(IDs,myPallOpt,(oneID)=>
{
    myHashSet.add(oneID);
});
```

So which is faster  Plan A or B?

Thanks

Comment: Hash sets are not thread-safe.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the CPU can keep up with the I/O from the database.. just make sure to stream the "large" I/O step. Anyway, voting to close because the question is for "fastest" although no problem/environment has been established. Use the 97/3 rule.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing as @SLaks...OP could use a ConcurrentDictionary though...unless the OP is okay with some of the items not actually getting added into the hashSet (or breaking in some other way).

Comment: @Xantix: That would probably be slower.

Comment: @SLaks or having a seperate hashSet for each thread and then combine them at the end...using one of the overloads to the Parallel.Foreach to provide that.

Comment: @Xantix: That would probably still be slower.

Comment: Is `var myHashSet = new HashSet(IDs);` not quick enough?

Comment: @SLaks probabably...it would depend on how long hashing an item takes and how many items..but with simple ids (Strings/longs) I think you are probably right.

Comment: @Xantix: Rebuilding the final hashset would still need to re-hash

Comment: Will your database service partial get requests over multiple connections quicker than a full request over one connection? We can't answer that based on the information provided. This is the crux of the question, the hash set performance is less relevant. (Although adding to a non-thread safe collection in parallel is destined for failure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashSet<T>` is not thread safe, so the second option (using `Parallel.ForEach`) will likely cause bugs.  It should definitely be avoided.

The best option is likely to just build the hashset directly from the results:

```
var myHashSet = new HashSet<int>(IDs);
```

Note that this only works if the `HashSet` is only intended to contain the items from this collection.  If you're adding to an existing `HashSet<T>`, a `foreach` (your first option) is likely the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Plan B likely won't work because it is likely not thread-safe (most .NET collection classes are not thread safe).  You could fix it by making access to it thread-safe, but that essentially means serializing access to it, which is no better than single threaded.  The only case it would make sense is if between beginning of your for loop and actual addition you have some cpu intensive processing that would be good to parallelize.